# Split values into column SQL

Tags: sql

I have 4 types of values in one single column and looking to split those values in 4 different columns using SQL.

This is my table:

```
Name   Car
---------------
John   Tesla
John   Renault 
John   Mercedes
John   VW
```

And I would like have this result:

```
Name  Car1    Car2     Car3      Car4
-----------------------------------------
John  Tesla Renault   Mercedes    VW
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to permanently change the table or just looking to display these results in a query?

Comment: Tag the `RDBMS` you are using

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything already? Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PIVOT for this.

Your example almost exactly matches the Microsoft help page, comment if you need more help-
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Right, I figured it out. I didn't realise that when you execute a SELECT function in SQL, you are actually creating a new column. I thought you just merged columns together.

So my code was simply:

```
   SELECT   
    (CASE WHEN car = "Tesla" THEN name ELSE Null END) as Car_type_1
    (CASE WHEN car = "Renault" THEN name ELSE Null END) as Car_type_2
    (CASE WHEN car = "Mercedes" THEN name ELSE Null END) as Car_type_3 
    (CASE WHEN car = "VW" THEN name ELSE Null END) as Car_type_4
```

Should have learnt the basics of SQL! Hope this helps anybody else in my situation.